# How to get Firebase secure data from angular or any other web platform

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here is my security rules and condition in firebase

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Product/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true; 
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

According to firestore documentation we can retrieve data at [once by this method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

```
db.collection("Product").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

How to retrieve secured data from Firebase. It will give back you data if it has a valid uid. What is the proper method to send my user status or uid on every request

Comment: You mean you want to send data his own data only? If UID is 1234 then he can access document named 1234 only. Like that ??

Comment: No. Any user who signup can access the data

Comment: Any registered user can READ the data. OK, and who can WRITE or modify the data?

Comment: For simplicity, I need only registered user can read and write

Comment: You just need to add this in rules then: `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;` ... Now only registered users can read/write.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper method to send my user status or uid on every
>   request.

You have to combine the [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules?authuser=0) with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start).

So, with Firebase Authentication you cover the **authentication** part of your system security (i.e. confirming users identity), and with the Security Rules you cover the **authorization** part (i.e. granting access to the system).

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start):

> To sign a user into your app, you first get authentication credentials
>   from the user. These credentials can be the user's email address and
>   password, or an OAuth token from a federated identity provider. Then,
>   you pass these credentials to the Firebase Authentication SDK. Our
>   backend services will then verify those credentials and return a
>   response to the client.
>
> After a successful sign in, you can access the user's basic profile
>   information, and you can control the user's access to data stored in
>   other Firebase products. You can also use the provided authentication
>   token to verify the identity of users in your own backend services.

So, concretely, you need to select the desired sign-in method(s) (i.e. passwords, phone numbers, federated identity providers like Google, Facebook and Twitter, etc.) and then implement one (or more) corresponding login function(s) in your application. Note that you could also use your own authentication mechanism, since JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) can be generated on you own server and used to authenticate users via the `signInWithCustomToken()` method.

After login, the authentication token will be automatically included in the requests to the Firebase back-end services (Firestore, Cloud Storage, etc.).

More details in the "Get Started with Firebase Authentication" [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start).

---

You will also find several tutorials on the web: https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+firebase+authentication+example

Comment: May be, I could not explain it properly. After login I can retrieve secured data. When I refresh browser, I could not retrieve data which is expected as on that time the Firebase  unable to find get UID

Comment: Do you use a specific persistence type, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?authuser=0#setpersistence

Comment: @AhmadSharif please edit you question then. The information you saying here may not be seen by everyone. Your question has nothing to do with refresh :-(